# I want to bind multiple concrete classes to an interface in Ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to bind multiple concrete classes to an interface in Ninject.

I have **ITestService** interface and concrete implementations **TestServiceA** and **TestServiceB**.

They are being bound like this:

```
kernel.Bind<ITestService>().To<TestServiceA>();
kernel.Bind<ITestService>().To<TestServiceB>();
```

In "**HomeController(ITestService service)**", I have this:

```
private ITestService _service;  

public HomeController(ITestService service) 
{   
     _service = service 
}

public ActionResult Index() 
{   
     ViewBag.Message = _service.GetMessage();
     return View(); 
}
```

It raises an error.  How can I fix it?

Comment: What is the error/exception message?

Answer (score 4):

That won't work.  You bound two things to the same interface and Ninject has no way to know which concrete class to materialize.  [Ninject offers contextual binding](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding) though.

An example:

```
// Setup your bindings with a name:
Bind<ITestService>().To<TestServiceA>().Named("A");
Bind<ITestService>().To<TestServiceB>().Named("B");


// Then in your controller, specify the name with an attribute:
public HomeController([Named("A")]ITestService service)
{   
     _service = service 
}
```